# Cakephp Exception

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In case of a exception i wish to store data in db (url,description,code,method,    referer,clientip,useragent)

- what is the best way to do and
- where is the best way to write code to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the [CakePhp Exceptions documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) is a good place to start.

I would recommend [creating a Exception handler class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler) that will handle all your custom logging needs.